# If there exist open, disjoint sets $A, B$ in $X, d$, then is $\bar A \cap B = A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Clearly $A, B$ are separated in $X, d$ if $A, B$ are closed and disjoint since $(A \cup A') \cap B = \emptyset$ and vice versa. For disjoint open sets, I cannot come to a conclusion. I tried constructing a set = {the limit points of $A\} = C$ but then what? Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $B$ is a subset of the closed complement of $A$ if $A$ is open and disjoint from $B$.

Comment: Where does that lead to, though? I'm going your route instead as it looks shorter. More hints? (I'd prefer if you answered at the "answers").

Comment: If $B$ is a subset of the closed complement of $A$, then so is $\overline B$, hence it is disjoint from $A$.

Comment: I can't believe I don't see these things sometimes.

Comment: @StefanH How can I assume that $\bar A$ is entirely contained in $X \setminus B$? Can't it have a possible intersection?

Comment: $A$ is a subset of the closed complement of $B$, so also $\bar A⊆X-B$.

Comment: is it because $A$ is closed? I'm just confused on "why", and thats the only part im confused. Am I overthinking it? @StefanH

Comment: No, it is because $B$ is open. Then $X-B$ is closed and contains $A$. SInce $\bar A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, it must $\bar A⊆X-B$. But that's exactly what Cameron wrote in his answer.

Comment: Otherwise $\bar B$ is closed! Correct?

Comment: What do you mean with "otherwise" ?

Comment: If $\bar A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then since intersections of closed sets are closed, so is that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want to say. We assume that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and that $A$ and $B$ are open. Since $B$ is open, it follows that $\bar A\cap B$ is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $B$ is open and disjoint from $A$, then $X\setminus B$ is a closed superset of $A.$ Since $\overline A$ is the smallest closed superset of $A$, then $\overline A\subseteq X\setminus B,$ and so $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset.$ Likewise, $A\cap\overline B=\emptyset.$